# How to combine PowerShell runspace stderr, stdout etc into a single stream

Tags: powershell, task, runspace

I'm looking for the equivalent of the PowerShell pipeline redirection *>&1 when running a job.

I run the jobs roughly like this:

```ps1
    $Instance = [PowerShell]::Create()
    $Instance.AddScript($CommandList)
    $Result = $Instance.BeginInvoke()
    $Instance.EndInvoke($Result)
```

The trouble is output is divided into multiple streams and to report it I must do this:

```
    $Instance.Streams.Debug
    $Instance.Streams.Error
    $Instance.Streams.Information
```

This groups messages by type rather than interleaving them so that there is no good way to tell where, within an execution, a given error was thrown.  If they were combined, the errors would appear immediately after relevant Write-Host statements.

There appear to be 5 streams(debug, error, information, progress, verbose and warning) and I'd like to combine them all although simply combining error and information would be a huge step forward.

I looked around the $Instance object and tried to find something under InitialSessionState for passing to Create() with nothing obvious presenting itself.

Answer (score 6):

To access output from all streams in output order when using the [PowerShell SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/windows-powershell), you'll have to resort to `*>&1` as well:

```
$Instance = [PowerShell]::Create()

# Example commands that write to streams 1-3.
$CommandList = 'Write-Output 1; Write-Error 2; Write-Warning 3'

# Wrap the commands in a script block (`{...}`) and call it using 
# `&`, the call operator, which allows you to apply redirection `*>&1`
$null = $Instance.AddScript('& {' + $CommandList + '} *>&1')

$Result = $Instance.BeginInvoke()
$Instance.EndInvoke($Result) # Returns output merged across all streams.
```

Since output objects from streams other than the success stream (`1`) have a uniform type that reflects the stream of origin, you can examine the type of each output object to infer what stream it came from - 
 see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53242893/45375) for details.

For more information about PowerShell's 6 output streams, run [`Get-Help about_Redirection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection).