# What decides if a value is returned from a PowerShell function?

Tags: function, powershell, powershell-7.0

I'm trying to figure out what dictates if a value is returned from a PowerShell function or not, and I've run into some oddities. The [about_return docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_return?view=powershell-7.1#long-description) say:

> In PowerShell, the results of each statement are returned as output, even without a statement that contains the Return keyword.

But this seems to glaze over details. If I run this:

```
function My-Function {
    1
    [System.Console]::WriteLine("Hello")
    $null
    $true
    $false
    0
    2
}
```

Running this returns an array of (along with printing "Hello"):

```
1
True
False
0
2
```

Which means that `$null` isn't auto-returned. Then I tried incrementing since I'm doing using that in a function:

```
function My-Function {
    $n = 1
    $n
    $n++
    ($n++)
    -join @(1, 2, 3)
    (-join @(1, 2, 3))
}
```

Returns:

```
1
2
123
123
```

So, `$n` and `$n++` were returned, but `($n++)` wasn't? But then when compared to another operator (`-join`), it's the same in each case. Why does wrapping parenthesis around `$n++` prevent it from being returned, and why don't other operators behave the same? This is even more confusing since the `=` operator appears to work in the opposite way:

```
function My-Function {
    ($n = 1)
    $n
    $n++
    ($n++)
}
```

Returns:

```
1
1
2
```

Now wrapping the assignment causes it to be returned, whereas wrapping `$n++` causes it to not be returned.

In summary, I'd just like to know a straightforward way of being able to look at a line of code in a function, and determine if it will cause a value to be returned or not.

Comment: Actually `$n++` was not returned and `($n++)` was returned.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Wow, somehow I managed to mixup pre and post incrementing. That's embarrassing.

Comment: What's nice about PS is that we can test everything on the console, I can't explain why right now but wrapping the incrementing variable with `( )` will force it to be returned to the console. When you do `$n = 0` then `($n++)`, `0` will be returned to stdout but `$n` will be equal to `1` (Not part of your code but put it as an example)

Comment: It’s called variable squeezing. Same thing happens from a normally silent variable assignment, it will also output

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon The embarrassing thing is I'm new to PowerShell, not writing code lol. And so the rule is, anything that evaluates to a value other than `$null` is returned, and some operators like assignment and incrementing only evaluate to a value if they're wrapped in parenthesis? Then there's a weird case I just found where `@($n = 1, 5)` evaluates to `$null`, which I find weird, but I think that's probably something unrelated.

Comment: I think `$null` can be returned from a function. If it couldn't, then `$x` in this example would still be equal to `'String'`: `$x = 'String'; function return-null { $null }; $x = return-null`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I'm realizing now that `$null` doesn't appear to show up in arrays when printed, which was causing confusion for me. If I print out the returned array using `-join` to insert a delimiter, yes, I can see that it is indeed returned, just not displayed. Thank you for you guidance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This section discusses the specific statements from your sample functions.
See the next section for background information.

- `$n = 1` and `$n++` are *assignments* and therefore do *not* produce output.
- `$n` is an *expression* whose value *is* output
- `$null` - ditto, but even though it is *output*, it doesn't *display* by default
- `($n++)` - due to enclosure in `(...)` - turns the *assignment* into an *expression* and therefore *does* output the assigned value (too).

  - However, because you've used the *post*-increment form of the assignment, it is the *old* value that is output, not the *now incremented* value; to increment first (pre-increment) and *then* output, use `(++$n)`
- `[System.Console]::WriteLine("Hello")` prints *directly to the console*, which *bypasses* PowerShell's system of [output streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams).

  - This means *you cannot capture or redirect such output* from inside PowerShell (see the next section).

---

#### PowerShell's output ("return value") behavior:

<sup>Tip of the hat to [iRon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1701026/iron) for his help.</sup>

**PowerShell**, following the model of traditional shells, is **organized around *streams*** - see the conceptual [about_Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection) help topic for an overview of all 6 streams that PowerShell supports.<sup>[1]</sup>

That is, **any statement - and therefore potentially *multiple* ones - in a script or function can write to any of the output streams**.

The ***primary* output stream, meant to convey *data***, is the ***success* output stream** (whose number is `1`), and **only *it* is sent through the [*pipeline*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines) by default**, and therefore by default only *it* is captured in a variable, suppressed, or redirected to a file.

There are **two ways** to **write to the success output stream**, i.e. to **produce *data* output**:

- ***Explicitly***, with a **[`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output)** call (**`echo`** is its built-in alias) - although that is **rarely needed**.

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76317309/45375) for a list of - unusual - situations, where `Write-Output` *is* needed / useful.
- **Typically *implicitly*, by neither capturing, suppressing, nor redirecting output produced by an expression, command, or language statement**.

  - In other words: **Output from any *command* (e.g., `Get-ChildItem *.txt`) or *expression* (e.g, `1 + 2` or `(42).ToString('x')`) or even *language statement as a whole* (e.g, `foreach ($i in 0..2) { 1 + $i }`) is sent to the success output stream *by default***.
  - Unlike in traditional programming languages, **[`return`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Return) is *not* needed to produce output** - in fact, its primary purpose is to exit the enclosing scope *independently* of any output the scope produces, though as a ***syntactic convenience*** you can *combine* the two aspects:

    - `return <command-or-expression>` is in effect the same as the following *two* statements, the first of which (potentially) produces output, the second of which exits the scope: `<command-or-expression>; return`
  - This *implicit output behavior* is convenient and and allows for concise, expressive code, but can also be a **pitfall**: **it is easy to *accidentally* produce output** - typically from a .NET method whose return value isn't needed (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65906608/45375) for an example).

    - iRon's [GitHub feature request #15781](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15781) discusses one potential way to remedy this problem: introduction of an opt-in strict mode that only permits using *explicit* output statements (`Write-Output`, `return`) in order to produce output.
    - [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53452660/45375) shows **troubleshooting techniques** you can use with the currently available features.

**As for [*assignments*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Assignment_Operators)** - e.g. `$n = 1; $n += 1; ++$n; $n--`:

- By default they **do *not* produce output**.

  - A *hybrid* case is the chaining form of a [multi-assignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_assignment_operators#assigning-multiple-variables), e.g. `$a = $b = 1`, which assigns `1` to *both* variables: statement-*internally*  the assignment value is passed through, but the statement *as a whole* has no output.
- However, **as an *opt-in* you can make them pass the value(s) being assigned *through* via `(...)`**, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--); e.g. `($n = 1)` both assigns `1` to variable `$n` *and* outputs `1`, which allows it to participate in larger expressions, such as `($n = 1) -gt 0`

  - Note that the related `$(...)` ([subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--)) and `@(...)` ([array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--)) do *not* have that effect - they wrap one or more *entire statement(s)*, without affecting the enclosed statements' intrinsic output behavior; e.g. `$($n = 1)` does *not* produce output, because `$n = 1` by itself doesn't produce output; however, `$(($n = 1))` *does*, because `($n = 1)` by itself does.

**As for output *enumeration behavior*:**

- By default, **PowerShell *enumerates* collections** that are being output, in the spirit of *streaming* output: That is, **it sends a collection's *elements* to the pipeline, *one by one***.
- In the rare event that you do need to output a collection *as a whole* - which in general should be avoided, so as not to confound other commands participating in a pipeline, which usually do expect *object-by-object* input - you have two options:

  - `, $collection` (sic; uses an aux. one-element wrapper array)
  - More explicitly, but less efficiently: `Write-Output -NoEnumerate $collection`
  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62489498/45375) for more information.

**As for outputting `$null`:**

- **`$null` *is* output to the pipeline**, but **by default *doesn't show***.

  - `$null` by itself produces no *visible* output,
  - but the following returns `$true`, demonstrating that the value *was* sent:

    ```bash
    $null | ForEach-Object { $null -eq $_ } # -> $true
    ```
- Note that **PowerShell also has an "array-valued `$null`" value** that it uses to represent the *lack of output* from a command, which is technically represented as the [`[System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull.Value) singleton. **In *expression* contexts, this values is treated the same as `$null`**, but **in the *pipeline* it behaves like an *enumerable without elements* and therefore sends *nothing* through the pipeline** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66410615/45375) for more information.

**As for *suppressing* (discarding) unwanted output / *redirecting to a file***:

- The best general-purpose way to **suppress a statement's *success* output** is to **assign to `$null`** (`$null = ...`); e.g.:

  ```bash
   # .Add() outputs a value, which is usually unwanted.
   $null = ($list = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()).Add('hi')
  ```

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55665963/45375) for a discussion and alternatives.
- Note: The following discusses output *suppression*, via `$null` as the redirection target, but applies analogously to redirecting output to a *file*, by specifying a file name or path as the target.<sup>[2]</sup>

  - To **selectively suppress a *different* output stream, prefix `>$null` with its [number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection); e.g. `3>$null`** suppresses warning stream output.
  - To **suppress output from *all* streams**, which in the case of *external programs* covers both stdout and stderr, use redirection **`*>$null`**.

**As for *merging* output streams**:

- **Only the *success* output stream (stream number `1`) can be merged into**.
- You can ***selectively* merge one or more output streams into it** (e.g. **`2>&1`** and/or `3>&1`), or **merge *all* (others)**: **`*>&1`**
- In the resulting merged success output stream you can still identify what (non-success) stream a given object came from, by examining its type; e.g., *error* stream objects (stream `2`) are [`[System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord) instances - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53242893/45375) for more information.

**As for *bypassing* PowerShell's system of streams:**

- **[`Out-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-host) and [`[Console]::WriteLine()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Console.WriteLine) calls *bypass* PowerShell's output streams** and write directly to the host / console (terminal). (A *host* is any environment that hosts the PowerShell engine, which is *typically*, but not necessarily a console (terminal); examples of other hosts are the [PowerShell SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/windows-powershell) and the host used in PowerShell [remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Remote)).

  - As such, **their output cannot be captured, suppressed or redirected from inside PowerShell**.
- **[`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host)** *formerly* unconditionally bypassed PowerShell's output streams and still goes to the host *by default*, but - since PowerShell version 5 - routes its output via the *information stream* (stream number `6`), where it *can* be captured / redirected on demand - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60534138/45375) for more information.

**As for how output is *formatted*:**

- If output isn't captured, suppressed, or redirected, it is sent to the host (console) by default, where it is rendered based on **PowerShell's rich and customizable *for-display output-formatting system***. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51805771/45375) for a concise overview.
- Note that the resulting representations are designed for the *human* observer, not for *programmatic processing*. While **PowerShell  maintains a clear separation between the actual *data* and *its representation***, the **caveat** is that you do end up with just the for-display, string representation in the following scenarios:

  - When you use [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) or its effective aliases, the redirection operators `>` and `>>`
  - When you (implicitly) send output to the *outside world* (an outside caller's stdout stream - see below).
  - In both cases, if later programmatic processing is required, the data must be transformed into a *structured* text format, such as CSV ([`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv) or [`ConvertTo-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv)) or JSON (using [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json)).

**As for how the *outside world* sees PowerShell's output streams:**

- IPC (inter-process communication) at the OS level knows only *two* output streams: *stdout* (standard output) and *stderr* (standard error), which forces PowerShell to map its 6 output streams onto these two in order to return streaming output to an outside caller.
- While it would make sense to map PowerShell's success output stream to stdout and *all other streams* to stderr, **unfortunately *all* streams are reported via *stdout* by default as of PowerShell 7.2** - although selectively redirecting stderr in the calling process (typically with `2>`) *does* send PowerShell's *error stream* (only) to that redirection target. See the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15669365/45375) for more information.
- Also note that **PowerShell as of version 7.2 only ever communicates via *text* (strings)** with **outside callers** as well as with **external programs called from inside a PowerShell sessions**, which means that **character-encoding issues** can arise - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64666821/45375) for more information.

---

<sup>[1] Note that PowerShell has no concept of an *input* stream as such, and therefore also does *not* support the stdin redirection operator `<` familiar from other shells. Instead, commands receive streaming input (only) *via the pipeline*. In order to receive data *from the outside world*, via the PowerShell [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh)'s stdin stream, the [automatic `$input` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#input) must be used - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38668360/45375).</sup>

<sup>[2] Using `>` (or `>>`) to redirect to a file effectively uses the [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) cmdlet behind the scenes, and therefore *its* default character encoding, which is "Unicode" (UTF-16LE) in *Windows PowerShell*, and BOM-less UTF-8 in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*. However, in PowerShell version 5.1 and above you can control this encoding via the [`$PSDefaultParameterValues` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#psdefaultparametervalues) - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42451413/45375).</sup>