# Run ps1 file in foreground

Tags: powershell

How to run a ps1 file in foreground?
I noticed when I execute my ps1 file, instead of view the log of the ps1 file execution, a Background job is started.
Is there anyway to run a ps1 file and get the same behavior we have when executing a sh or batch file?

Updates:

1. My ps1 file:

```
$scratchOrgName=$args[0]

Write-Host "Hello " & $scratchOrgName
```

2. ps1 file execution:
   [image]

Comment: `&` is an alias for [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job?view=powershell-7.2) in PowerShell Core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `&` starts a new process. (It's called the [background operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#background-operator-))

Change the code into something like

```
Write-Host "Hello" $scratchOrgName
```

or

```
Write-Host "Hello $scratchOrgName"
```

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**

Unless you explicitly request that commands be run in the background (as you *accidentally* did, see next section), PowerShell commands do run in the foreground.

To achieve what you were (presumably) trying to do:

```sh
$scratchOrgName=$args[0]

"Hello $scratchOrgName"
```

---

[Michaël Hompus' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70569628/45375) provides the crucial pointers, but let me attempt a systematic overview:

`Write-Host "Hello " & $scratchOrgName` is composed of *two* statements:

- `Write-Host "Hello " &` submits command `Write-Host "Hello "` as a [background job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Jobs), in *PowerShell (Core) v6+* (in *Windows PowerShell* (v5.1-), you'd get an *error*, saying that `&` is reserved for future use). An object representing the newly created job is output and prints to the screen, as shown in your screenshot.

  - The *post-positional* use of `&` - i.e. placed *after* a command - is indeed the [background operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#background-operator-), and is therefore equivalent to `Start-Job { Write-Host "Hello " }`
  - This contrasts with *pre-positional* use of `&`, which then acts as the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-), for invoking command names or paths that are potentially *quoted* or contain / are *variable values* (e.g. `& 'C:\Program Files\Node.js\node.exe'`)
- `$scratchOrgName` - by virtue of [PowerShell's implicit output behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69792182/45375) - outputs the value of that variable, which prints to the screen by default.

---

As for **what you intended**:

- `&` is VBScript's *string-concatenation* operator; its PowerShell equivalent is `+`
- A string-concatenation operation is an *expression*, and as such it must be *enclosed in `(...)`* in order to be passed *as an argument* to a *command* such as `Write-Host`.

Therefore, the direct PowerShell expression of your intent would be:

```sh
Write-Host ("Hello " + $scratchOrgName)
```

But, as also shown in Michaël's answer, this is more easily expressed via an [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings):

```sh
Write-Host "Hello $scratchOrgName"
```

Taking a step back:  [`Write-Host` is typically the wrong tool to use](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/), unless the intent is to write *to the display only*, bypassing the success output stream and with it the ability to send output to other commands, capture it in a variable, or redirect it to a file.

To output a value, use it *by itself*, taking advantage of the aforementioned implicit output behavior (or use [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output), though that is rarely needed):

```sh
"Hello $scratchOrgName"
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60534138/45375) for more information.

Comment: That's a great and helpful answer. Thank  you!