# Blank records when returning ArrayList of PSObjects from function

Tags: powershell, arraylist

So I'm refactoring a Powershell script and moving a lot of stuff into functions. When I return an ArrayList of 42 PSObjects from a function (called Get-OutList) with `return $out`, 42 blank records are inserted into the beginning of the ArrayList, and my original records then follow.

My function looks like this:

```
function Get-OutList {
    param (
        [Parameter(Position=0,mandatory=$true)]
        [PSObject]$RoleCollection,
        [Parameter(Position=1,mandatory=$true)]
        [PSObject]$MemberCollection
    )

    $out = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    $MemberCollection.result | ForEach-Object {
        $currentMember = $_
        $memberDetail = New-Object PSObject
        Add-Member -InputObject $memberDetail -MemberType NoteProperty -Name FirstName -Value $($currentMember.user.first_name)
        Add-Member -InputObject $memberDetail -MemberType NoteProperty -Name LastName -Value $($currentMember.user.last_name)
        Add-Member -InputObject $memberDetail -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Email -Value $($currentMember.user.email)
        Add-Member -InputObject $memberDetail -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Status -Value $($currentMember.status)
        
        $RoleCollection.result | ForEach-Object {
            Add-Member -InputObject $memberDetail -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $_.name -Value (&{If($currentMember.roles.name -contains $_.name){"Y"}Else{""}})
        }
        $out.Add($memberDetail)
    }
    return $out
}
```

I understand Powershell enumerates each record back to where the function was called, and I've tried a few things to no avail:

- Behaviour is the same in PS v5.1.x and v7.3.0.
- Returning with `return @($out)` makes no difference (i.e. results in a System.Object with 42 blank records followed by my 42 original records for a total of 84 records).
- Returning with `return Write-Output -NoEnumerate $out` results in a System.Object with 42 blank records and my 42 original records nested in a 43rd record.
- Typing the result of the function call as ArrayList with `$results = [System.Collections.ArrayList](Get-OutList)` makes no difference.

Why can't I get my object to be the same as before it's returned from a function?? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit #1**
Including an easily-reproducible example:

```
function Get-OutList {
    param (
        [Parameter(Position=0,mandatory=$true)]
        [PSObject]$MemberCollection
    )

    $out = New-Object 'System.Collections.ArrayList'
    $MemberCollection | ForEach-Object {
        $memberDetail = New-Object PSObject
        Add-Member -InputObject $memberDetail -MemberType NoteProperty -Name FirstName -Value "One"
        Add-Member -InputObject $memberDetail -MemberType NoteProperty -Name LastName -Value "Two"
        Add-Member -InputObject $memberDetail -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Email -Value "Three"
        Add-Member -InputObject $memberDetail -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Status -Value "Four"
        $out.Add($memberDetail)
    }
    return $out
}

$members = @("Joe Bloggs", "Some Dude", "The Dude")

$memberDetails = Get-OutList -MemberCollection $members
Write-Output $memberDetails
```

If you add a breakpoint before $out is passed back, you'll see there are three records, and if you keep stepping, you should see $memberDetails will have six records (the first three blank).

**Edit #2**
Appears there's no such problem when using Generic.List instead of ArrayList. Used `$out = [System.Collections.Generic.List[PSObject]]::new()` instead of `$out = New-Object 'System.Collections.ArrayList'` and it's working just fine.

Comment: Without knowing what you are passing to your function it is very hard to tell, on the other hand, your function makes me feel you're over-complicating it. Provide a minimal reproducible example and will likely be able to help you.

Comment: @NathanC - you REALLY should NOT output a collection unless there is no other way to do the job. it's better [and easier] to output one object and allow the caller to gather things into whatever collection they want. ///// as it is, i wonder if you are seeing an example of by-reference versus by-value. you may need to look into [icky! nasty! yucky!] explicitly setting the scope for your collection $Var.

Comment: Just to avoid confusion: the extra output you're seeing aren't _blank_ objects, but _integers_ that are the return values from the `$out.Add($memberDetail)` method calls, which unintentionally "pollute" your function's output stream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem stems from the fact that the **[`System.Collections.ArrayList.Add()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.ArrayList.Add) method has a *return value***  (the index at which the object has been added) and that that return value - as would happen with *any* .NET method that  returns a value -  **becomes part of your function's "return value", i.e. *stream of output objects***.

This is a manifestation of **PowerShell's *implicit output behavior***, which is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69792182/45375).

Notably, `return` is *not* needed in PowerShell to produce *output* from a function - any statement can produce output. `return $foo` is simply syntactic sugar for `Write-Output $foo; return` or, relying on *implicit* output behavior, `$foo; return`

Therefore, the **immediate fix** to your problem is to ***discard* (suppress) the implicit output produced by your `$out.Add($memberDetail)` call**, which is typically done by assigning the call to `$null` (there are other methods, discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55665963/45375)):

```
# Discard the unwanted output from .Add()
$null = $out.Add($memberDetail)
```

[In your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70922224/45375), you *indirectly* applied that fix by switching to the [`` System.Collections.Generic.List`1 ``](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.List-1) list type, whose `.Add()` method has *no* return value. It is for that reason, along with the ability to *strongly type* the list elements, that `` System.Collections.Generic.List`1 `` is generally preferable to `System.Collections.ArrayList`

---

**Taking a step back:**

In simple cases such as yours, where the entire function output is to be captured in a list, you can take advantage of the output-stream behavior and simply **emit each output object *individually* from your function** (from the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) script block) and **let *PowerShell* collect the individual objects emitted** in a list-like data structure, which will be a regular PowerShell *array*, namely of type `[object[]` (i.e., a *fixed-size* analog to `System.Collections.ArrayList`):

This is not only more convenient, but also performs better.

Applied to your sample function:

```
function Get-OutList {
  param (
      [Parameter(Position=0,mandatory=$true)]
      [PSObject]$MemberCollection
  )

  $MemberCollection | ForEach-Object {
    $first, $last = -split $_
    # Construct and implicitly output a custom object.
    [pscustomobject] @{
      FirstName = $first
      LastName = $last
      Email = 'Three'
      Status = 'Four'
    }
  }
  # No need for `return` - all output objects were emitted above.
}

$members = @("Joe Bloggs", "Some Dude", "The Dude")

# By assigning the function's output stream to a variable,
# the individual output objects are automatically collected in an array
# (assuming *two or more* output objects; if you want an array even if 
# only *one* object is output, use [Array] $memberDetails = ...)
$memberDetails = Get-OutList -MemberCollection $members

# Output (implicitly).
$memberDetails
```

Also note the use of the `[pscustomobject] @{ ... }` syntactic sugar for simplified custom-object creation - see the conceptual [about_Object_Creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Object_Creation?view=powershell-7.3#create-custom-objects-from-hash-tables) help topic.

Answer (score 0):

Used `$out = [System.Collections.Generic.List[PSObject]]::new()` instead of `$out = New-Object 'System.Collections.ArrayList'` and it's working just fine. No extra blankies.