# How to add foreach-object -parallel output to a dictionary/arraylist

Tags: powershell, dictionary, foreach-object

I'm trying to get all the stale branches from Azure DevOps to nag the developers to remove them.
If I use this script below, I get all the results I want, but it takes ages to process.

```
$resultlist = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

function Get-StaleBranches {
    $dateString = (Get-Date).AddDays(-90).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    $date = [datetime]::parseexact($dateString, 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss', $null)
    $reposArray | ForEach-Object {
        $repo = $PSItem
        $refsUri = "url"
        $refs = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $refsUri -Method get -Headers $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader).value
        foreach($branch in $refs){
            $splitName = $branch.name.Substring(11)
            $commitUri = $using:OrgUri + "url"
            $commits = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $commitUri -Method get -Headers $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader).value
            $commitDate = [datetime]::parseexact($commits.author.date, 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss', $null)
            if($commitDate -lt $date -and $splitName -notlike "develop" -and $splitName -notlike "release" -and $splitName -notlike "master")
            {
                $result = @{}
                $result.repo = $repo
                $result.branch = $splitName
                $result.date = $commitDate
                $result.author = $commits.author.name
                $result.email = $commits.author.email
                $resultlist.Add((New-Object PsObject -Property $result)) | Out-Null
            }
        }
    }
}

Get-StaleBranches
```

To speed it up, I tried using the `foreach-object -parallel` functionality like this:

```
$threadSafeDictionary = [System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary[string,object]]::new()

function Get-StaleBranches {
    $dateString = (Get-Date).AddDays(-90).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    $date = [datetime]::parseexact($dateString, 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss', $null)
    $reposArray | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
        $dict = $using:threadSafeDictionary
        $repo = $PSItem
        $dict.$repo = @()
        $refsUri = "url"
        $refs = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $refsUri -Method get -Headers $using:AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader).value
        foreach($branch in $refs){
            $splitName = $branch.name.Substring(11)
            $commitUri = "url"
            $commits = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $commitUri -Method get -Headers $using:AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader).value
            $commitDate = [datetime]::parseexact($commits.author.date, 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss', $null)
            if($commitDate -lt $using:date -and $splitName -notlike "develop" -and $splitName -notlike "release" -and $splitName -notlike "master")
            {
                $dict.$repo += [PSCustomObject]@{
                    Branch = $splitName
                    Date = $commitDate
                    Author = $commits.author.name
                    Email = $commits.author.email
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Get-StaleBranches
```

However, now all branches in the dictionary are doubled. Did I make a mistake somewhere? Is there any other way to approach this?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you run a test for me?  I found the += ran slow. So I changed From : $dict.$repo = @() and $dict.$repo += [PSCustomObject]@.....  TO : $dict.$repo = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new() and $dict.$repo.Add( [PSCustomObject]@.......)

Comment: Hi, first of all, I'm now getting some numbers in console output, it goes extremely fast for first 30 seconds and then starts outputting numbers at a speed of around 4 per second until it gets to 617. Do you know what that is? But the doubled entries are no longer there, so that must've been related to the += somehow. Thank you so much.

Comment: The number is the result of the return value from the `.Add()` call getting implicitly output - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70928244/45375). While you can fix that with `$null = ....`, there's no good reason to use an array list to begin with - just let PowerShell collect the outputs _automatically_ for you - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708579/45375).

Comment: You don't even need a `ConcurrentDictionary` if you just rely on PowerShell's implicit output behaviour. So just write that `[PSCustomObject]@{…}` literal without assigning it to anything. Collect output from the function instead: `$staleBranches = Get-StaleBranches`.

Comment: Thanks @mklement0, so if I understand the 2nd link correctly, instead of the `$dict.$repo += ...` part, I should just leave the object declaration and add the object on the same level as I'm doing the `$dict.$repo = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()`?

Answer (score 3):

I have no explanation for your symptom, but I recommend simplifying your code as follows, which will also speed it up:

- Avoid the explicit use of (synchronized) data structures and instead let *PowerShell* collect loop output in an *array* for you, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708579/45375), which works with *any* command output (and therefore also with `ForEach-Object [-Parallel]` and a `foreach` loop statement).

The following simplified example shows how to do that:

```bash
function Get-StaleBranches {
  # Implicitly output what the ForEach-Object -Parallel script block outputs.
  (1..5).ForEach({ 'repo' + $_ }) | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    # Create and implicitly output a custom object for each repo.
    [pscustomobject] @{
      Repo   = $PSItem
      Results = foreach ($branch in (1..3).ForEach({ 'branch' + $_ })) { 
        # Create and implicitly output a custom object; all such objects
        # created in this `foreach` loop are collected in the .Results property.
        [pscustomobject] @{
          Branch = $branch
          Date   = Get-Date
        }
      }
    }   
  }
}
```

Note:

Calling `Get-StaleBranches` outputs a *stream* of (nested) `[pscustomobject]` instances, which, when captured in a variable, become an `[object[]]` array.

Display output:

```bash
Repo  Result
----  ------
repo1 {@{Branch=branch1; Date=2/6/2023 11:53:33 AM}, @{Branch=branch2; Date=2/6/2023 11:53:33 AM}, @{Branch=branch3; Date=2/6/2023 11:53:33 AM}}
repo2 {@{Branch=branch1; Date=2/6/2023 11:53:33 AM}, @{Branch=branch2; Date=2/6/2023 11:53:33 AM}, @{Branch=branch3; Date=2/6/2023 11:53:33 AM}}
repo3 {@{Branch=branch1; Date=2/6/2023 11:53:33 AM}, @{Branch=branch2; Date=2/6/2023 11:53:33 AM}, @{Branch=branch3; Date=2/6/2023 11:53:33 AM}}
repo4 {@{Branch=branch1; Date=2/6/2023 11:53:33 AM}, @{Branch=branch2; Date=2/6/2023 11:53:33 AM}, @{Branch=branch3; Date=2/6/2023 11:53:33 AM}}
repo5 {@{Branch=branch1; Date=2/6/2023 11:53:33 AM}, @{Branch=branch2; Date=2/6/2023 11:53:33 AM}, @{Branch=branch3; Date=2/6/2023 11:53:33 AM}}
```

This isn't the same as returning a *dictionary* keyed by branch names, but it isn't hard to adapt the solution to do that:

```bash
$dict = @{}  # initialize output dictionary (hashtable)
Get-StaleBranches | 
  ForEach-Object {
     # Create an entry for the repo at hand.
     $dict[$_.Repo] = $_.Results
  }

# Output the resulting dictionary.
$dict
```

Display output (the `Name` column contains the dictionary's key values):

```bash
Name     Value
----     -----
repo4    {@{Branch=branch1; Date=2/6/2023 12:01:42 PM}, @{Branch=branch2; Date=2/6/2023 12:01:42 PM}, @{Branch=branch3; Date=2/6/2023 12:01:42 PM}}
repo2    {@{Branch=branch1; Date=2/6/2023 12:01:42 PM}, @{Branch=branch2; Date=2/6/2023 12:01:42 PM}, @{Branch=branch3; Date=2/6/2023 12:01:42 PM}}
repo5    {@{Branch=branch1; Date=2/6/2023 12:01:42 PM}, @{Branch=branch2; Date=2/6/2023 12:01:42 PM}, @{Branch=branch3; Date=2/6/2023 12:01:42 PM}}
repo3    {@{Branch=branch1; Date=2/6/2023 12:01:42 PM}, @{Branch=branch2; Date=2/6/2023 12:01:42 PM}, @{Branch=branch3; Date=2/6/2023 12:01:42 PM}}
repo1    {@{Branch=branch1; Date=2/6/2023 12:01:42 PM}, @{Branch=branch2; Date=2/6/2023 12:01:42 PM}, @{Branch=branch3; Date=2/6/2023 12:01:42 PM}}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the suggestion from the comment already helped immensely in speeding up the script, I will try this approach tomorrow morning.