# Porting concurrent Bash code to Powershell

Tags: bash, powershell

I have the function below for writing storage (`sync` on Unix):

```
# Sync Progress Function
function syncStorage {

  printq "Writing storage, may take more than 5 minutes."
  printq "Although it seems slow, consider this process like flashing an ISO to a USB Drive."
  printq "Below is an innacurate indicator of mB left to write. It may decrease hundreds of megabytes in seconds."

  # shellcheck disable=SC2016
  sync & {
    # If the unsynced data (in kB) is greater than 50MB, then show the sync progress
    while [[ $(grep -e Dirty: /proc/meminfo | grep --color=never -o '[0-9]\+') -gt 5000 ]]; do
      SYNC_MB=$(grep -e Dirty: /proc/meminfo | grep --color=never -o '[0-9]\+' | awk '{$1/=1024;printf "%.2fMB\n",$1}')
      echo -en "\r${SYNC_MB}"
      sleep 1
    done
  }

  echo

  #watch -n 1 'grep -e Dirty: /proc/meminfo | grep --color=never -o '\''[0-9]\+'\'' | awk '\''{$1/=1024;printf "%.2fMB\n",$1}'\'''
  #grep -e Dirty: /proc/meminfo | grep --color=never -o '[0-9]\+' | awk '{$1/=1024;printf "%.2fMB\n",$1}'
}
```

I want to port it to Powershell, and have done this so far:

```
sync & {
      # If the unsynced data (in kB) is greater than 50MB, then show the sync progress
      # You can replace contents in $(...) with 5001 for testing purposes
      while ( $(grep -e Dirty: /proc/meminfo | grep --color=never -o '[0-9]\+') -gt 5000 ) {
        SYNC_MB=$(grep -e Dirty: /proc/meminfo | grep --color=never -o '[0-9]\+' | awk '{$1/=1024;printf "%.2fMB\n",$1}')
        echo -en "\r${SYNC_MB}"
        sleep 1
      }
    }
```

Powershell accepts this syntax, but returns:

```
Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------  
45     Job45           BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost 

      # If the unsynced data (in kB) is greater than 50MB, then show the sync progress
      while ( 43289423 -gt 5000 ) {
        SYNC_MB=$(grep -e Dirty: /proc/meminfo | grep --color=never -o '[0-9]\+' | awk '{$1/=1024;printf "%.2fMB\n",$1}')
        echo -en "\r${SYNC_MB}"
        sleep 1
      }
```

It doesn't run the code, it just prints it out. The same behavior persists when you replace the $(...) with any value (e.g. 5001 to satisfy the while loop) in the while loop's condition. Any ideas?

Comment: `sync` will be executed as a job (since `&` is the [Background operator `&`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#background-operator-) in PS Core) and then what follows is a script block which gets displayed to the console as it is. It's not clear what you want to accomplish with the syntax `sync & { ... }`

Comment: Yes, I'd like to run the commands concurrently, so that while `sync` is running, it prints out the remaining MBs to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While superficially similar, **`{ ... }` in Bash vs. PowerShell are fundamentally different**:

- In Bash, it is a way to group statements to be executed *instantly*, directly in the caller's scope.
- In PowerShell, it is a way to group statements into a [*script block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks), which is a reusable unit of code to be executed *on demand*, either in a *child scope*, via `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-), or directly in the caller's scope, via `.`, the [dot-sourcing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-).

  - If you output a script block *by itself*, as you did, *no* execution happens and its *verbatim content* (sans `{` and `}`) prints to the display .

By contrast, in *both* shells, a *post-positional* `&` serves to asynchronously launch a *background job*, which in PowerShell (Core only) is the implicit equivalent of using the [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job) cmdlet.

Therefore, the following Bash call pattern:

```sh
# Bash: These are really two separate statements:
#       `sync &` to launch `sync` in the background, 
#       and `{ ...; }` to execute commands synchronously in the foreground.
# For clarity, you could place the statements on separate lines.
sync & { ...; }
```

corresponds to the following in PowerShell:

```sh
# PowerShell:
# Note: You may prefer `&` to `.` in order to create a child scope
#       whose variables are limited to that scope.
# Here too you could place the statements on separate lines.
sync & . { ... }
```

---

Separately, there are **problems with your translation of your Bash code to PowerShell**:

- Unlike in Bash, variable assignments in PowerShell:

  - require the `$` sigil there too; e.g., `$SYNC_MB = ...` instead of `SYNC_MB=...`
  - As the above juxtaposition shows, PowerShell also permits whitespace to surround `=`, the [assignment operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Assignment_Operators).
- Unlike in Bash, PowerShell's [`-gt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-gt) isn't exclusively *numeric*: it serves as the single greater-than operator that also works with *string* LHS values, in which case it performs *lexical* comparison.

  - Therefore, in order to perform numerical comparison with an LHS that is the output from an external program such as `grep`, which is invariably a *string*, you need to *cast it to an appropriate number type*, typically `[int]`; to provide simple examples:

    ```sh
    (/bin/echo 10) -gt 2 # !! $false - LEXICAL comparison

    [int] (/bin/echo 10) -gt 2 # OK: $true - NUMERICAL comparison
    ```
- Unlike in Bash, `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--) is rarely needed outside [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings):

  - In variable assignments, you need no operator at all.
  - To make a command's output participate in a larger expression, it is usually better to use `(...)`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--)
- `echo` doesn't refer to the external `/bin/echo` utility, but is a built-in alias of the [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output) cmdlet, which understands neither the `-en` options nor `\`-escaped escape sequences, given that PowerShell uses `` ` ``, the so-called backtick, as its escape character.

  - While you could call `/bin/echo` via its full path, the PowerShell way is to use the [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host) cmdlet, as shown below.
  - Alternatively, as you've discovered, PowerShell has a dedicated cmdlet for progress displays, [`Write-Progress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-progress), but note that its downside is that it can slow the overall operation down noticeably.
- Due to a long-standing and highly unfortunate bug, PowerShell - up to at least 7.2.2 - doesn't properly pass `"` chars. embedded in external-program arguments, necessitating their *manual `\`-escaping*, even inside [verbatim (single-quoted) string (`'...'`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings), such as in your `awk` command.

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375) for more information.

To put it all together, using `&` for child-scoped execution of the script block, and assuming that `sync` is either a PowerShell *script* (`sync.ps1`) or an *external utility*, placing the statements on separate lines:

```sh
sync &
& {
  while ([int] (grep -e Dirty: /proc/meminfo | grep --color=never -o '[0-9]\+') -gt 5000 ) {
    $SYNC_MB = grep -e Dirty: /proc/meminfo | grep --color=never -o '[0-9]\+' | awk '{$1/=1024;printf \"%.2fMB\n\",$1}'
    Write-Host -NoNewLine "`r${SYNC_MB}"
    sleep 1
  }
}
```

Note: If `sync` were a PowerShell *function*, the above wouldn't work, because background jobs do not share state with the caller and know nothing about its functions (except functions provided via auto-loading [modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules)).

Comment: Thanks :D. This is a great answer! I ended up replacing Write-Host with Write-Progress, like https://pastebin.com/GNwuz68n

Comment: Glad to hear it, @MilkyDeveloper. Good point re `Write-Progress`; I've added it to the answer (note the potential performance caveat). Please also see my update re the pitfall re `-gt`, which in PowerShell performs lexical comparison with a string LHS, which is why an `[int]` cast is needed.

Comment: @MilkyDeveloper, just looked at your link: To avoid the `-gt` pitfall, define your `getSyncKB` function as follows: `function getSyncKB { [int] (grep -e Dirty: /proc/meminfo | grep --color=never -o '[0-9]\+') }` - note that there's also no need for `return`, which in PowerShell is only needed to explicitly exit a scope. PowerShell scripts and functions do not have return values, they emit to the success output stream, PowerShell's analog to stdout, as Bash scripts and functions do - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69792182/45375) for details.