# Expanding variables and squeezing in Powershell

Tags: powershell

```
$i = 0
```

`"$($i++)"` #will output nothing

`"$(($i++))"` #will output the old value of $i

Additionally, typing `$i++` and `($i++)` directly on the console will do the same.

Why? I still don't exactly understand what $() does.

Comment: If you want to increase first and then output, the `++` goes before the variable not after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--) is primarily useful in [expandable (double-quoted) strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings),  `"..."`, which is indeed what you're trying to use it for.

It does *not* modify the (often implicit) output behavior of the pipeline(s) it encloses.

**`++$i` and `$i++` are specialized *assignment* statements, which, like all assignment statements, *do not produce pipeline output***, but the assigned values *can* act as *expression operands*.

In order for regular, `=`-based assignments to participate in an expression, they need to be enclosed in `(...)`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--), which for `++$i` and `$i++` isn't strictly necessary; e.g., `++$i + 1`

**Using an `(...)`-enclosed assignment *by itself* in a pipeline** also *outputs* the assignment value; that is, it **passes the value being assigned *through*** to the pipeline.

- As a by-design variation, the *post*-[increment/decrement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Assignment_Operators#the-increment-and-decrement-operators) assignments, when enclosed in `(...)` or participating in an expression, pass the variable's *current* value through, *before* updating the variable with the incremented/decremented value.

Therefore, increment / decrement assignments (`++` / `--`) too must be enclosed in `(...)` in order to produce output: `(++$i)` and `($i++)`

**Inside `"..."`, you must therefore use *both* `(...)` *and* `$(...)`**:

```
$i = 0
"$((++$i))" # -> 1
"$(($i++))" # -> 1 (but $i contains 2 afterwards.
```

For a more comprehensive overview of PowerShell's output behavior, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69792182/45375).