# How to use powershell as native messaging host?

Tags: powershell, google-chrome-extension, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, chrome-native-messaging

My requirement is to read the content from the file and send it to the chrome browser extension. I am using native messaging. I did all the configuration for native messaging but failed to send messages from the native messaging host to the extension.
I am getting error like "Error when communicating with the native messaging host".
I got to know that it was due to the wrong implementation of the native messaging protocol.

The Actual protocol from native messaging is :
**"The same format is used to send messages in both directions: each message is serialized using JSON, UTF-8 encoded and is preceded with 32-bit message length in native byte order. The maximum size of a single message from the native messaging host is 1 MB, mainly to protect Chrome from misbehaving native applications. The maximum size of the message sent to the native messaging host is 4 GB."**

My code is as below:
native-messaging-example-host.ps1:

```
$file = "D:\temp\test\test.txt"
$data = Get-content $file -Raw
$Objectdata = $data |ConvertFrom-Json
$formatedData = $Objectdata |Select-Object -Property message |ConvertTo-Json -Depth 1 -Compress
$encconsumerkey= [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new().GetBytes($formatedData)
$Writer = New-Object System.IO.BinaryWriter([System.Console]::OpenStandardOutput());
$Writer.Write([Int32]$encconsumerkey.length)
$Writer.Write($encconsumerkey)
$Writer
$Writer.Flush()
$Writer.Close()
```

My Batch Script which calls the above PowerShell script

MyExample1.bat

```
@echo off
color 1F
echo.

C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "D:\projects-repo\CromeNativeMessaging\NativeHost\native-messaging-example-host.ps1"

:EOF
echo Waiting seconds
timeout /t 10 /nobreak > NUL
```

NativeMessageHello.json

```
{
    "name": "native.messaging.trail.example",
    "description": "My Example1",
    "path": "D:/projects-repo/CromeNativeMessaging/NativeHost/MyExample1.bat",
    "type": "stdio",
    "allowed_origins": [
      "chrome-extension://lknkdjfamgnamaeaebinefklcobjpphm/"
    ]
  }
```

Someone please help me where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Does the native messaging host write a log file or does it have a parameter to enable logging? This could be helpful in determining the root of the problem.

Comment: On a side note, it is good practice to use parameter `-Raw` with `Get-Content`, when `ConvertFrom-Json` is involved. The latter works more predictable, when fed a single (possibly multiline) string instead of an array of strings (when `-Raw` is omitted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that your script is being called from outside PowerShell via the PowerShell *CLI* ([`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) for Windows PowerShell, [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) for PowerShell (Core) 7+).

**There are two problems with your script, one potential, the other definite - *I am not certain that fixing them is enough to solve your problem*:**

- A potential problem is that the [`[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.Encoding.UTF8) encoding is an encoding *with BOM*,<sup>[1]</sup> whereas it's safe to assume that Chrome does *not* expect your data to have a BOM in this scenario and *may* fail on encountering one.

  - To obtain a BOM-*less* UTF-8 encoding, use `New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding` instead, or, in PowerShell v4 and above, [`[System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.UTF8Encoding).
- A definite problem is the `$Writer` statement (the line containing only `$Writer`) in your code, which causes *implicit* output<sup>[2]</sup> to PowerShell's success [output stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams), which is *relayed via stdout* to an outside caller, in the form of a formatted representation of the `$Writer` object (that is invariably *text*).

  - That is, this statement "pollutes" the binary data you're sending to stdout.

    - In general, prepending `$null =`  suppresses unwanted implicit output;<sup>[3]</sup> here, it seems you can simply remove the statement.
  - The same goes for the batch file that wraps your PowerShell command: it too mustn't produce its own stdout output, so you must either remove the `echo` commands or redirect their output to *stderr*, with `>&2`

---

<sup>[1] in .NET Framework and as of .NET 6; changing this is being discussed for a future .NET version.</sup>

<sup>[2] See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69792182/45375) for more information about PowerShell's implicit output behavior.</sup>

<sup>[3] See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55665963/45375) form more information about output suppression.</sup>