# Not quoting $input in Powershell, and its value is "Current"

Tags: powershell, input, stdin, quoting

I was writing a PowerShell script, and forgot to quote `$input` when piping to a command. The command unexpectedly appeared to receive the string `Current` on stdin, so I investigated further and typed the following:

```
PS C:\> echo $input

Current
-------
```

```
PS C:\> echo "$input"
```

The difference in output between these two statements confuses me, and I'm not sure what to search for to understand this better. I would have expected both to output nothing, like the second command.

What does "Current" mean? Is this a general quote behaviour, or something specific to `$input`?

Comment: Something specific, as [`$Input`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables#input) is an **automatic variable**.

Comment: Note that current is underlined.  This suggests that is a field name.  The contents appear blank.

Comment: `Current` is the name of the field/column. Run any other cmdlets like Get-ChildItem and notice the column name

Comment: [`Current`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator.current?view=net-7.0#system-collections-ienumerator-current) is a property of any class implementing the `IEnumerator` interface and, as @iRon points out, `$input` is a PowerShell builtin enumerator.

Comment: Would echoing any enumerator do something similar? And, why does it behave differently with quotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on the helpful comments:

- The [automatic `$input` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#input) is managed *by PowerShell*, and represents *input from the pipeline* in appropriate contexts.
- As such, use of `$input` as a *user* variable, for custom purposes, should be *avoided*.
- To use `$input`,  do *not* use it with [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output) (whose built-in alias is `echo`): either use `$input` *as is* in the pipeline, or, to force instant enumeration, use `@($input)`.

---

As for **what you tried**:

> ```bash
> echo $input
> ```

This is effectively the same as `Write-Output $input`, given that `echo` is a built-in alias of the [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output) cmdlet.

PowerShell's [for-display output-formatting system](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/format/formatting-file-overview) uses a *reflection-based* approach for types that (a) do not have *predefined formatting data* associated with them and (b) are neither *strings* no (quasi) primitive .NET types such as *numbers*.

Instances of such types are represented by their *public properties*, and instances up to 4 properties are implicitly formatted with [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table), instances with 5 or more properties implicitly with [`Format-List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-list).

The automatic `$input` variable is an *enumerator* that represents the current context's pipeline input.

`$input.GetType().FullName` reveals that `$input` is an instance of the `System.Collections.ArrayList+ArrayListEnumeratorSimple` class.

It isn't directly obvious, but this - non-public - class is what the [`System.Collections.ArrayList`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.ArrayList)'s `.GetEnumerator()` method returns, which is an enumerator class that implements the [`System.Collections.IEnumerator`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.IEnumerator) interface, which you can verify as follows: `$input.GetType().GetInterfaces()`

This interface has one public property, `.Current`, which you can verify as follows, using PowerShell's [intrinsic `psobject` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members#psobject): `$input.psobject.Properties.Name`

Therefore, `Write-Output $input` implicitly uses `Format-Table` to render the `$input` instance's one and only property, `.Current`, which is what you saw.

Irrespective of how many elements the enumerator represents - *none* outside a pipeline - the `.Current` property value is `$null` and therefore *not showing* in the output, since the `.MoveNext()` method isn't being called in this case.

Example:

```bash
function foo { Write-Output $input }
1..3 | foo  # !! Still prints a table with an empty "Current" column.
```

In short: **Passing `$input` as-is to `Write-Output` is virtually *pointless*.**

- The to-display output is always unhelpful, as shown above.
- In the pipeline: `Write-Output $input | & someCommand` is:

  - equally useless if `someCommand` is an *external program* (executable), because it is *also* the for-display representation that is sent (as a stream of strings (lines)), given that PowerShell only "speaks text" when communicating with external programs, as of PowerShell 7.3.1
  - *does* work if `someCommand` is a *PowerShell* command (whether built-in or custom), but there is no benefit to using `Write-Output` in that scenario just using `$input` *by itself*, taking advantage of PowerShell's [implicit output behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69792182/45375), is both more concise and more efficient.

Given the above, the current behavior (which analogously also affects `Write-Host`) - as of PowerShell 7.3.1 - could be considered a *bug*, and has been reported in [GitHub issue #18826](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/18826).

Examples:

```bash
# !! USELESSS, because findstr.exe receives the *for-display*
# !! representation of the enumerator, line by line.
# Note: The findstr.exe call simply passes each line it receives through.
1..3 | & { Write-Output $input | findstr.exe '^'  }

# OK, due to using a *PowerShell* command,
# but there's no good reason to use Write-Output here.
function foo { Write-Output $input | ForEach-Object { "[$_]" } }
1..3 | foo # -> '[1]', '[2]', '[3]'

# Preferred approach, because it is both simpler and more efficient:
# *implicit* output of $input, which causes enumeration.
function foo { $input | ForEach-Object { "[$_]" } }
1..3 | foo # same as above
```

---

> ```bash
> echo "$input"
> ```

Enclosing `$input` in `"..."`, i.e. in an [expandable string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings), forces it to be *stringified*.

Unlike when you pass `$input` to `Write-Output`, using it inside `"..."`:

- causes *enumeration* of the enumerator (in essence, repeatedly calling `.MoveNext()` on it while it returns `$true`, and then accessing its `.Current` property)
- with the resulting (stringified) objects joined with spaces, which is how PowerShell stringifies arrays (collections)

*Outside of a pipeline*, `$input` is an enumerator *without elements*, which causes `"$input"` to evaluate to the *empty string*, which, in terms of *display output* results in an *empty line*.

An example of how it acts *in a pipeline*:

```bash
'one', 2 | & { "[$input]" }
```

Output:

```bash
[one 2]
```

That is, the (stringified) input objects were joined with a single space.

(A single space is the *default* separator. Technically, you can specify a different one via the [`$OFS` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#ofs), although that is rarely done in pratice).

In short: **While `"$input"` does force enumeration, it may not do what you want**, given that:

- for *non-string* input, the original type identity is *lost*.
- even for *string* input, multiple input strings end up *as one, single-line string*, with the input strings separated with spaces, as discussed above.

Examples:

```bash
# OK: Input strings are passed one by one (as lines) to findstr.exe
'foo', 'bar' | & { $input | findstr.exe '^' }

# !! DIFFERENT: "$input" forces collecting the inputs in an array,
# !! which is then stringified; therefore a *single string* containing
# !! 'foo bar' is sent.
# !! Using Write-Output "$input"` would behave the same.
'foo', 'bar' | & { "$input" | findstr.exe '^' }
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you. My script was doing something like `Write-Output "$input" | &$foo` and using `$input` in a pipeline. Without the quotes, it always seemed to contain `Current`, with the hyphens and newlines, but with quotes, it contains the contents of stdin passed to the script. But given your answer I would have expected the unquoted form to produce the first input object below the hyphens?

Comment: That is to say,  `"hello" | &{Write-Output "$input"}` gives `hello`, but `"hello" | &{Write-Output $input}` always gives `Current` with `-------` and several newlines. Is the second command just listing properties of the `$input` enumerator?

Comment: @craig65535, please see my update, but the short of it is: Using `$input` with `Write-Output` is pointless - just use `$input` by itself, which causes implicit enumeration. Yes, when you use `Write-Output $input` and send its output _to the display_ (which is what happens by default), no enumeration takes place, and the enumerator object's `Current` property is shown in tabular format. Because the enumerator's `.MoveNext()` method is not being called, `Current` is always `$null`, which in tabular display output results in an empty column value.

Comment: When I had `Write-Output $input | &$foo`, the $foo program definitely received `Current` etc.  I don't think this behaviour is specific to the display/console. Honestly I still don't really understand. That said, `$input | &$foo` does work as well as `Write-Output "$input" | &$foo` so I'll switch my script to use that.

Comment: (To be clear, `$foo` contains a path to an exe file that reads from stdin)

Comment: @craig65535, I neglected to consider _external programs_ in my explanation - please see my update. The short of it is: external programs - unlike PowerShell commands - also receive the _for-display_ representations of (complex) objects, _as a stream of lines_. The update both explains this, and, at the bottom, why you probably don't want to use `"$input"` (with or without `Write-Output`).

Comment: @craig65535, I've also decided to report the current `Write-Output` behavior as a bug: see [GitHub issue #18826](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/18826).