# Error adding to array: Cannot find an overload for "Add" and the argument count: "1"

Tags: json, powershell, scripting

I can't for the life of me work out how to add elements to an array inside a foreach loop.
I keep getting the error:

```
   8 |      $logs.Add(@{
     |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Cannot find an overload for "Add" and the argument count: "1".
MethodException: C:\Users\michael.dawson\OneDrive - Sage Software, Inc\Documents\Source_Control\secrets-dashboard-script\function\Calculate\recreate-error2.ps1:8:5
```

I can get it to work outside of a foreach, but I've been scratching my head for ages :-(
Here's the code:

```
$logs = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$logs = $null
$logs = @{}

Get-Service | ForEach-Object {
    $appCreds = $_

    $logs.Add(@{
        "test"      = $appCreds.DisplayName;
        "message"   = "blah"
    })
}  

$logs | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
```

Appreciate any help guys. Cheers.

I'm expecting some JSON a bit like this:

```
  {
    "message": "blah",
    "test": "Optimise drives"
  },
  {
    "message": "blah",
    "test": "Dell Client Management Service"
  },
  {
    "message": "blah",
    "test": "DeviceAssociationBroker_1592b90"
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am in rush but, I want to help.  Try the example below.

```
$logs = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

Get-Service | ForEach-Object {
    $appCreds = $_

    $logs.Add(@{
        "test"      = $appCreds.DisplayName;
        "message"   = "blah"
    }) | out-null
}  

$logs | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```bash
$logs = 
  Get-Service |
  ForEach-Object {
    @{
      test    = $_.DisplayName;
      message = "blah"
    }
  }  

$logs | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
```

The above takes advantage of:

- Being able to use the results of entire commands *as expressions*, relying on PowerShell *implicitly* collecting the command's output objects in the target variable, `$logs` - *as-is* in the case of a *single* output object, and as an *array* (of type `[object[]]` in the case of *two ore more* output objects.
- PowerShell's [implicit output behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69792182/45375), where the output (result) from a command or expression is *implicitly* output.

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `$logs = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList`
> `$logs = $null`
> `$logs = @{}`

Each statement *overrides* the previous one, so that `$logs` ends up containing `@{}`, i.e. an empty [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables).

Thus, a later `$logs.Add(...)` call with a *single* argument predictably fails, because a hashtable's [`.Add()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Hashtable.Add) method requires *two* arguments, namely a key and and a value, *separately* - which isn't what you intended, however.

While you could have avoided this problem by making do with just `$logs = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList` as the variable initialization, given that that type's [`.Add()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.ArrayList.Add) method accepts any single object to append to the list, the solution at the top shows a PowerShell-idiomatic solution that is both simpler and more efficient.