# how to convert three decimal into 2 decimal of versions list in a file using powershell

Tags: powershell, sorting, scripting, azure-powershell

I have a PowerShell script which is collecting vm image version lists and sorting into descending order with the highest value:

```
$imagegallery = Get-AzGallery -ResourceGroupName rg-shared-inva-eastus
Write-Output $imagegallery.Name

$imagegallerydefinitioninfo = @("PeriscopeMQ","PeriscopeApp","PeriscopeWeb")

foreach ($imagedefinition in $imagegallerydefinitioninfo) {
      $imagegalleryimageversion = Get-AzGalleryImageVersion -GalleryName $imagegallery.Name -ResourceGroupName $imagegallery.ResourceGroupName -GalleryImageDefinitionName $imagedefinition
      Write-Output $imagegalleryimageversion.Tags.PeriscopeVmImageVersion |Sort-Object -Descending { [regex]::Replace($_, '\d+', { $args[0].Value.PadLeft(2)}) }   
}
```

Output is :

```
5.11.4
5.11.3
5.11.2
5.11.1
5.11.0
5.10.56
5.10.55
5.10.9
5.10.8
5.10.7
5.10.6
5.9.98
5.9.97
5.9.96
5.9.93
5.8.90
```

I want to convert this into 2 places decimals like:

```
5.11
5.10
5.9
5.8
```

and, find the highest version which is `5.11` and skip the `02`, and delete the third version.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use the `.ToString(int fieldCount)` overload to print [`[version]` (`System.Version`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Version) instances only by their first two fields (`.Major` and `.Minor`); a simple example:

```bash
# -> '1.2'
([version] '1.2.3.4').ToString(2)
```

Note that you can sort `[version]` instances as-is, which allows you to apply the `.ToString()` call to the *result* of your [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object) call; if the `.PeriscopeVmImageVersion` property values are version *strings* rather than `[version]` instances, you can cast to `[version[]]`:

```bash
[version[]] $imagegalleryimageversion.Tags.PeriscopeVmImageVersion |
  Sort-Object -Descending |
  ForEach-Object ToString 2 | 
  Get-Unique
```

<sup>Note: 
* `ForEach-Object ToString 2` is [simplified syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Simplified_Syntax) for: `ForEach-Object { $_.ToString(2) }`
* `Write-Output` is intentionally *not* used; the command relies on PowerShell's *implicit output behavior* in the first pipeline segment, which is both more concise and efficient (and doesn't change the syntax requirements). For background information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69792182/45375).</sup>

The (rarely used) [`Get-Unique`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-unique) cmdlet is used to output only *one* string for each group of versions sharing the same major and minor values.<sup>Tip of the hat to [Andrew Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1115360/andrew-morton).</sup>

---

To apply the sorting and formatting *across all loop iterations* (across all image-gallery definitions), use the following (note the switch to [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) and the use of the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_) to refer to the pipeline input object at hand:

```bash
$imagegallerydefinitioninfo |
  ForEach-Object {
    $imagegalleryimageversion = Get-AzGalleryImageVersion -GalleryName $imagegallery.Name -ResourceGroupName $imagegallery.ResourceGroupName -GalleryImageDefinitionName $_
    [version[]] $imagegalleryimageversion.Tags.PeriscopeVmImageVersion
  } |
  Sort-Object -Descending |
  ForEach-Object ToString 2 | 
  Get-Unique
```

---

To address your final requirement, which I understand to be the following:

- In each group of version numbers sharing the same major and minor field values, find the *highest* one.
- From the 2 groups representing the highest version numbers overall, remove the highest version each, representing the images to *keep*.
- Output the remaining versions in descending order.

```bash
$groupIndex = 0
$imagegallerydefinitioninfo |
  ForEach-Object {
    $imagegalleryimageversion = Get-AzGalleryImageVersion -GalleryName $imagegallery.Name -ResourceGroupName $imagegallery.ResourceGroupName -GalleryImageDefinitionName $_
    [version[]] $imagegalleryimageversion.Tags.PeriscopeVmImageVersion
  } |
  Group-Object -Property Major, Minor | 
  Sort-Object -Descending { $_.Group[0] } |
  ForEach-Object { 
    if (++$groupIndex -le 2) {
      $_.Group | Sort-Object -Descending | Select-Object -Skip 1
    } else {
      $_.Group | Sort-Object -Descending
    } 
  } |
  ForEach-Object ToString # ... process further as needed.
```

- [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) is used to *group* the version numbers by shared major and minor field values.
- `For-EachObject ToString` prints the `[version]` objects as strings with *all* fields, so you can verify that the correct versions are reported; you may want to capture the `[version]` output as-is, so you can use it in a VM removal command.

With your sample input, this in effect eliminates the following two version numbers from the input: `5.11.4` and `5.10.56`.

Comment: Hi @mklement0, The last part didn't worked well, gettiing below output:

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      10     62     -1      
5      11     9      -1      
5      4      416    -1      
5      5      102    -1      
5      6      247    -1

its not arranging with Descending order and not skipping correct version

Comment: @SheikhSadique, yes, there were logic errors in the solution, sorry. Please see my update, which hopefully now produces the desired output - assuming I understood the requirements correctly..

Comment: No, I want , supoose I have these images
5.11.4
5.11.3
5.11.2
5.11.1
5.11.0
5.10.56
5.10.55
5.10.9
5.10.8
5.10.7
5.10.6
5.9.98
5.9.97
5.9.96
5.9.93
5.8.90
5.8.10
5.7.98

so it should take 5.11.* is latest or highest version
And, skip 2 more versions like 5.10.* and 5.9.* and delete all remaining older versions e.g 5.8.90
5.8.10
5.7.98, in this

Comment: @SheikhSadique, I'm still unclear on your requirements. Are you saying you want the highest version numbers from the first 3 groups _returned_ rather than _removed_? Using your latest sample data, please spell out the desired result _in full_.

Comment: @SheikhSadique, without clear requirements, no one will be able to help you. If you have trouble expressing the requirements in the limited space and with the limited formatting capabilities in _comments_, consider asking a _new question_ that focuses only on the one remaining task.