# Powershell Write-Output is a default output behaviour. The question is why do we need it at all?

Tags: powershell

As described here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output
all Write-Output does is sends the output to the current output device, which is a default anyway.

It appears, that the only advantage of having explicitly used Write-Output is the ability to provide a parameter -NoEnumerate. Is that correct?

If not, then what are other cases for using Write-Output?

Comment: Can be also useful to flatten a collection. And thats about it

Comment: I believe it mostly exists for consistency (there is one cmdlet for each of the standard [streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_output_streams?view=powershell-7.3)) and to provide some inter-language compatibility (`echo` is an alias for `Write-Output`).

Comment: thank you @zett42, yes, "consistency" seems to be the right description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main advantage really comes down to readability of your code, as it becomes easy at a glance to see that you're sending something to the output.

For instance, even with something as simple as

```
$foo = "Current date is $(get-date)"
```

I would argue that scanning through lines of code it's far easier to instantly understand what's happening when you see

```
Write-Output $foo
```

than if you just see

```
$foo
```

on a line of its own.

It's perhaps worth noting that shortened forms appear to be going out of popularity, or no longer being recommended in the same way. For instance if you edit Powershell code with VS Code you'll perhaps notice it showing warnings for the use of aliases, for instance `ft` aliasing `Format-Table`, `select` aliasing `Select-Object` etc, with the same listed reasoning that it makes it harder to maintain the code.

Comment: When starting with PowerShell, I had similar thoughts, using `Write-Output` for readability. Now I think that in many situations where you rely on PowerShell's implicit output behavior, `Write-Output` would actually make the code less readable, due to its verbosity. Also there is a performance penalty due to the additional function call. I like my code style to be consistent, so I've refrained from using `Write-Output`, but I add a comment when a variable stands on its own line, e. g. `$foo  # output` to make my intentions clear.

Answer (score 2):

Let me complement [Keith Langmead's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76306686/45375) with a - hopefully exhaustive - *list* of reasons to use [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Write-Output):

- For a discussion of PowerShell's *implicit* output behavior, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55665963/45375).

**(Debatable) readability: `Write-Output` as an explicit signal of the intent to produce output:**

- Keith's answer suggests that use of `Write-Output` helps readability and maintainability in that it signals the intent to produce output *explicitly*.
- [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42) notes that this can make code *more verbose* and also incurs a *performance penalty*, causing him to prefer *implicit* output, but decorating it *with a comment* to signal the intent; e.g. `$foo # output`
- I agree: Making explicit what the language implicitly provides is redundant, and may give rise to the misconception in inexperienced readers of the code that `Write-Output` is *required* (analogous to how you *actually* need `echo` in `cmd.exe` and Bash, for instance; as noted `echo` is a *built-in alias* of `Write-Output` in PowerShell); to the experienced reader, such calls amount to noise.
- In a manner of speaking, explicit `Write-Output` use expresses an ongoing disagreement with one the language's core features, which - while unfamiliar to users of *other* languages - can be *embraced*, resulting in more concise, distraction-free code that also performs better.

**Outputting arrays (list-like collections) *as a whole*, i.e. as a single object, with `Write-Output -NoEnumerate`**:

- As you note, the `-NoEnumerate` switch can be used to achieve that; e.g.:

  ```bash
   # -> 'Array has 3 elements', i.e. $_ refers to the *entire array*
   #    created with (1..3), due to -NoEnumerate.
   Write-Output -NoEnumerate (1..3) | 
     ForEach-Object { "Array has $($_.Count) elements." }
  ```
- However, there is a more concise - albeit somewhat obscure to beginners - and better-performing alternative: use of the *unary* form of `,` the [array constructor operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#comma-operator-) to wrap an array in a *transient, single-element array*, which, when enumerated in the pipeline as usual, results in the wrapped array being sent as a whole:

  ```bash
   # -> 'Array has 3 elements', i.e. $_ refers to the *entire array*
   #    created with (1..3), due to wrapping (1..3) in a 
   #    transient, single-element wrapper array.
   , (1..3) | 
     ForEach-Object { "Array has $($_.Count) elements." }
  ```

***Flattening* arrays (`... | Write-Output`):**

- As [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) points out, piping multiple arrays to `Write-Output` implicitly *flattens* them, i.e. returns a single-dimensional array that contains all the elements of the input arrays; e.g.:

  ```bash
  # Create a jagged array (an array of arrays)
  # -> @( @(1, 2, 3), @(4, 5) )
  $arrayOfArrays = (1..3), (4..5)

  # Flatten it by piping to Write-Output:
  # -> @(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
  $arrayOfArrays | Write-Output
  ```

***Use with [common parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters)*, notably `-OutVariable` and `-PipelineVariable`:**

- `-OutVariable` (`-ov`) allows you to save `Write-Output`'s output to a variable of choice while also sending the output through the pipeline.
- `-PipelineVariable` (`-pv`) saves each output object to a variable of choice that can then be accessed in the *script block* arguments of subsequent pipeline segments.
- Note: Given that these are *common* parameters, you won't need `Write-Output` if your output is produced by *cmdlets* or the cmdlet-like [advanced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced) functions and scripts, because you can use these parameters *directly* with such commands. However, you do need `Write-Host` in order to use these common parameters if the output is produced by *simple* functions and scripts or *external programs*; e.g. (these are contrived, but simple examples):

  ```bash
   # Stores the output from cmd /c dir /b /A:d in variable $dirOutput
   # but also sends it through the pipeline to Measure-Object
   Write-Output -OutVariable dirOutput (cmd /c dir /b /A:d) | Measure-Object

   # Stores each directory name output by cmd /c dir /b /A:d in 
   # variable $thisDir and previews (-WhatIf) a Rename-Item operation
   # that prepends "new_" to each directory name.
   Write-Output -PipelineVariable thisDir (cmd /c dir /b /A:d) |
     Rename-Item -NewName { "new_" + $thisDir } -WhatIf
  ```

***Syntactic convenience*: creation of arrays of (simple) strings:**

- Given that strings as *command arguments* only need quoting if they contain special characters, notably *spaces*, use of `Write-Output` offers a syntactically simpler alternative to array literals.
- Additionally, you can then omit `,` between the elements, given that `Write-Output` allows specifying arguments *individually*.
- This technique is probably best limited to *interactive* use and "throw-away" scripts.
- For instance; note that elements with metacharacters (e.g. `two and a half`) would need quoting either way (`'two and a half'`):

  ```bash
  # Array literal (@(...) enclosure is optional)
  @('one', 'two', 'three')

  # Syntactically simpler Write-Output equivalent, using its 'echo' alias:
  echo one two three
  ```