# Is it safe to omit "return" in Powershell Functions?

Tags: powershell

When do I need to use the verb `return` in Powershell? My functions work even if I omit this. I have written a simple Powershell Function to clarify my question.

**Works:**

```
function Get-StringTime {

    (Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd")

}
```

**Also works:**

```
function Get-StringTime {

    return (Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd")

}
```

Comment: Whenever you want to exit early

Comment: You should use it whenever you want your function to _return_ control to the caller.

Comment: But this happen in both cases

Answer (score 2):

> Is it safe to omit "return" in Powershell Functions?

If your function body only has a single *control flow path*, then **yes**!

The sample function you've shown has no branching (no `if` statements and no ternary statements), and thus satisfies the criteria above.

*It's worth noting that PowerShell scripts and functions don't have well-defined **return parameters**, they simply just emit output zero or more times throughout their life-cycle - in sharp contrast to many other object-oriented languages that have a similar `return` keyword*

---

> When do I need to use the verb return in Powershell?

As alluded above, the `return` **keyword** is a so-called *flow control statement*, and you should use it whenever you want your function to *return control* to the caller.

As discussed above, the sample function you've shown has no branching and simply needs to return control to the caller *after the first and only statement in it*, so `return` doesn't make a difference.

Let's write a function that has a more complicated control flow:

```
function Get-Factorial {
  param([int]$N)

  if ($N -le 1) {
    1
  }
  else {
    $N * (Get-Factorial ($N - 1))
  }
}
```

This function recursively calculates the factorial (`N! => 1 * 2 * ... * N`) of a given integer.

Let's say we wanted to get rid of that last `else` block:

```
function Get-Factorial {
  param([int]$N)

  if ($N -le 1) {
    1
  }

  $N * (Get-Factorial ($N - 1))
}
```

But now we have a problem - `Get-Factorial` will now *always* call itself regardless of the current value, and we'll end up with a StackOverflowException!

Here's where we can now use `return` - to `return` in case we hit `$N -le 1`!

```
function Get-Factorial {
  param([int]$N)

  if ($N -le 1) {
    # now we won't recurse if we hit this if block
    return 1
  }

  # this code will only be reached when we haven't returned already
  $N * (Get-Factorial ($N - 1))
}
```

To summarise:

- The `return` keyword is a *flow control statement*
- Therefore: use it when you need to modify the control flow of your code

Answer (score 0):

To complement [Mathias' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76851135/45375) with a **conceptual summary**:

- The purpose of [`return`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Return) is *flow control*:

  - It *instantly* exits the current function (or script file or script block) and returns control to the caller - as opposed to automatically returning when the end of the current function or script is reached.
  - It is therefore only ever *needed* for exiting the current scope *prematurely*.
- It acts independently of PowerShell's *output behavior* ("return values"), but - as *syntactic sugar* - you may *optionally* use it to *also* write to the success output stream before returning; that is:

  ```bash
  return (Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd")
  ```

  - is *syntactic sugar* for the following two separate statements:

    ```bash
     (Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd") # *implicitly output* the result
     return                          # exit the scope.
    ```
  - `return` is therefore *not* needed to *produce output* (a "return value").
  - Conversely, when `return` *is* optionally used to produce output, be aware that *it isn't guaranteed to be the only output*, given that any preceding statements may have produced output too (either *implicitly* or via the (rarely needed) [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output) cmdlet); that is:

    ```bash
     42                                      # *implicit output*
     return (Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd")
    ```

    - produces *two* output objects: `42`, and the result of the `(Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd")` call.
  - For more information about PowerShell's implicit output behavior, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69792182/45375).