# PowerShell unrolling arrays differently in function vs. script block

Tags: arrays, powershell, parameter-passing, scriptblock

I have an array of hashmaps as follows, and I would like to compute the sum of the `x` property for each item in the list:

```
$Items = @(
    @{x = 110; y = 108 },
    @{x = 102; y = 100 },
    @{x = 116; y = 114 }
)
```

The following function does so correctly:

```
function Get-SumXFunction {
    Param($Items)
    $Measured = $Items | Measure-Object -Sum x
    return $Measured.Sum
}
```

But I ultimately want to use this function as a parameter in another function, and I read on this site that the correct way to do this in PowerShell is using a script block. So, I rewrote the function using a script block as follows:

```
$GetSumXScriptBlock = {
    Param($Items)
    $Measured = $Items | Measure-Object -Sum x
    Write-Output $Measured.Sum
}
```

(Note that I have changed `return` to `Write-Output`, as my understanding is that this is necessary to be able to assign the output of the script block to a variable later on.)

But the script block, when called using `.Invoke($Items)`, doesn't do the sum at all! It just returns the `x`-value of the first item:

```
Write-Host "Get-SumXFunction:" (Get-SumXFunction $Items)
Write-Host "Get-SumXScriptBlock:" ($GetSumXScriptBlock.Invoke($Items))
```

```
Get-SumXFunction: 328
Get-SumXScriptBlock: 110
```

**Why does the script block give different results than the function? How can I write my function as a script block that produces correct results?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ***immediate* fix** is to use an aux. single-item array to wrap your array of hashtables:

```
$GetSumXScriptBlock.invoke((, $Items))
```

Note:

- It is the signature of the [`.Invoke()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.Invoke) method that makes this necessary: its only parameter is of type: `params object[]`, which means that passing an array causes *its elements* to be considered *individual arguments* to pass to the script block, so that only the *first* hashtable in your array is passed to the - first and only - parameter of your script block, `$Items`.
- Using the unary form of `,` the [array constructor operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#comma-operator-), wraps your array of hashtables in an outer, single-element array, therefore causing its only element - the array of hashtables - to be passed *as a whole* as the first positional script-block argument.

---

The ***preferable* fix** is to **invoke your script block with `&`**, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-) rather than via the `.Invoke()` method, which allows you to use the **usual [argument-mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing) syntax**:

```
& $GetSumXScriptBlock $Items
```

Note:

- Using the `.Invoke()` method to execute a script block in PowerShell code (as opposed to when using the PowerShell SDK, typically from C#) is best avoided in general, not just to for syntax reasons, but also because it changes the semantics of the call in several respects. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59220711/45375) for more information.

---

**As for `return` vs. `Write-Output` in your code:**

> I have changed `return` to `Write-Output`, as my understanding is that this is necessary to be able to assign the output of the script block to a variable later on.

`Write-Output` is *not* necessary in your script block, and neither is `return` - both are equivalent in your case, and can be simplified:

In essence, a function is also a script block, only a *named* one (as is a script *file*).

In PowerShell code in general, you can use *implicit* output, and you need `return` only for explicit flow control.
Thus, just `$Measured.Sum` *by itself* as the last statement in both script blocks is sufficient.

For more information about:

- PowerShell's *implicit output behavior*, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69792182/45375).
- `return`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76853970/45375).

Comment: Welp, that covers it! Thank you for your help.