# .bat file on Powershell: linux command is not understood

Tags: windows, powershell

Implementing .bat file `test.bat` which simply echos "test" on Powershell(administrater mode) results into incomprehensible error.

```
PS C:\Users\naoki> echo "echo test" > test.bat
PS C:\Users\naoki> test.bat

C:\Users\naoki>e
'e' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、
操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。
```

It seems the computer does not understand `echo` command and somehow it picks up the first letter of `echo` which is "e" and appends "" in front of it.

What's wrong?

Any information would be appreciated.

## Environment

Windows11

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr**

- Your problem is one of *character encoding*, caused by the use of `>`.

  - As an aside: As many shells on Unix-like platforms (e.g. Bash) do, `cmd.exe`, the interpreter of batch files, has a an *internal* (built in) `echo` command. Unlike Windows, Unix-like platforms also have an *external utility* by that name.
- Instead of `>`, use [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) with `-Encoding Oem` to write batch files from PowerShell:

```
"echo test" | Set-Content test.bat -Encoding Oem
```

<sup>Note: I've omitted `echo` before `"echo test"` above, because its explicit use isn't necessary in PowerShell - it is *implied*;  see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69792182/45375) for more information.</sup>

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `echo "echo test" > test.bat`

`>`, the [redirection operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection), is in effect an alias of the [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) cmdlet.

- In *Windows PowerShell* its default encoding is "Unicode" (UTF-16LE) with a BOM, which `cmd.exe` (the interpreter of batch files) fundamentally doesn't understand (not even with the `/U` option), resulting in the error you saw.<sup>[1]</sup>
- While in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) `>` / `Out-File` now more sensibly uses BOM-less UTF-8, `cmd.exe` doesn't *fully* understand this, because it expects non-ASCII-range characters (e.g., `è`) to be encoded according to the console's active code page, which defaults to the legacy system locale's OEM code page.

  - That said, if the content you're writing comprises ASCII-range characters *only*, you *could* get away with `>` in PowerShell 7+.
  - Similarly, if you've configured your system to use UTF-8 *system-wide* (which has far-reaching consequences - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375)), then `>` would *fully* work in PowerShell 7+

---

<sup>[1] Specifically, the first two bytes, i.e. the UTF-16LE BOM, are interpreted as (non-sensical) *content*, and the `NUL` byte that is the second byte in the two-byte sequence that makes up the encoding of the letter `e` makes `cmd.exe` stop parsing the file. An attempt is then made to execute the resulting string - the misinterpreted BOM with `e` appended - as a command, which - given that no such command exists - results in the "is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file" error message shown (in translated form) in your question.</sup>