Why do DataSet and DataTable references behave differently when loaded with ReadXml?
Description
I am trying to save and load a DataSet with two DataTables from a file in PowerShell using ReadXml.
I can reference the DataTables in the original DataSet with $dataset.Tables["language"] or $dataset.Tables["replace"], however once loading data from the file the resulting object will not return data when using named references, only $loadedDataSet.Tables[0] and $loadedDataSet.Tables[1].
Is there a reason for this that I am not seeing or is this a limitation or possibly a bug?
Code:
#Create a DataSet
$dataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$dataSet.DataSetName = "languages"

# Create the language DataTable
$languageDataTable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$languageDataTable.TableName = "language"

# Add columns to the language DataTable
$languageDataTable.Columns.Add("value", [string])
$languageDataTable.Columns.Add("name", [string])

# Add rows to the language DataTable
$languageDataTable.Rows.Add("en", "en (English)")
$languageDataTable.Rows.Add("sv", "sv (Swedish)")


# Create the conversion DataTable
$conversionDataTable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$conversionDataTable.TableName = "replace"

# Add columns to the conversion DataTable
$conversionDataTable.Columns.Add("from", [string])
$conversionDataTable.Columns.Add("to", [string])

# Add rows to the conversion DataTable
$conversionDataTable.Rows.Add("eng", "en")
$conversionDataTable.Rows.Add("fre", "fr")

#Add DataTables to DataSet
$dataSet.Tables.Add($languageDataTable)
$dataSet.Tables.Add($conversionDataTable)

# Save the DataSet to an XML file
function Save-DataSetToXml {
    param (
        [System.Data.DataSet]$dataSet,
        [string]$filePath
    )
    $dataSet.WriteXml($filePath, [System.Data.XmlWriteMode ]::WriteSchema)
}

# Load the DataSet from an XML file

function Load-DataSetFromXml {
    param (
        [string]$filePath
    )
    $ds = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $ds.ReadXml($filePath, [System.Data.XmlReadMode]::ReadSchema)
    return $ds
}


# Save the DataSet to an XML file
Save-DataSetToXml -dataSet $dataSet -filePath "data.xml"

# Load the DataSet back from the XML file
$loadedDataSet = Load-DataSetFromXml -filePath "data.xml"


Expecations and Results
$dataset.Tables["language"]
results in
value name        
----- ----        
en    en (English)
sv    sv (Swedish)

$loadedDataSet.Tables["language"]
results in
 

$loadedDataSet.Tables[0]
results in
value name        
----- ----        
en    en (English)
sv    sv (Swedish)

I expect them all to return the same output since the objects are identical (at least to my knowledge).
Troubleshooting
I am not sure how to troubleshoot this but I have tried alternating XmlWriteMode and XmlReadMode however it didn't make any difference.

Common issue, .ReadXml produces output and if not captured or redirected becomes your function's output thus $loadedDataSet becomes an object[] instead of a DataSet. An array with 2 elements, the first item is the XmlReadMode outputted from .ReadXml and the second element was the actual DataSet. $null = $ds.ReadXml($filePath, [System.Data.XmlReadMode]::ReadSchema) fixes it.

Surprised however that this is marked as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69791276/what-decides-if-a-value-is-returned-from-a-powershell-function however. I would never have thought to search for that thread and not sure I would have understood how it applies to my case regardless. Maybe it's just me.

added a new link that has answers more similar to the issue you had in this question
